# All placeholders disappear when using tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    case 'input':
                        echo '<div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="placeholder">
                                <img src="images/person.png" />
                                <span class="placeholder-text">First name </span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" id="adi" name="adi"/>
                            </div>';
                    break;
                    case 'input1':
                        echo '<div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="placeholder">
                                <img src="images/person.png" />
                                <span class="placeholder-text">Last name</span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" id="soyadi" name="soyadi"/>
                            </div>';
                    break;





    $(function () {
    $("input").on("blur", function () {
        var elem = $(this).parent().find(".placeholder");
        $(this).val() == "" ? elem.show() : elem.hide();
    });
    $(".placeholder").on("click", function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().find("input").focus();
    });

    $(window).keyup(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 9 && $('#adi:focus').length) {
            $("input").parent().find(".placeholder");
            $(".placeholder").hide();       
        }
        if (code == 9 && $('#soyadi:focus').length) {
            $("input").parent().find(".placeholder");
            $(".placeholder").hide();
        }
    });

});
```

I have a form with two html input text fields.

I want a placeholder to disappear when using the tab key. But when I use tab key all placeholders disappear. Any suggestions?

Comment: Reason you are not just using the placeholder attribute? Reason it hides is you are selecting all of them with `$(".placeholder").hide();`. And the line `$("input").parent().find(".placeholder");` does nothing.

Comment: Is all of that `case` code at the top PHP? If it is, you need to separate it from your JS. If it isn't, that's not valid JS.

Comment: I seperated them but thanks for warning. Yes I see the first line of code does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $("input").parent().find(".placeholder");
    $(".placeholder").hide();
```

Both of these lines are off.
The first doesn't really do anything, but I think your logic is off. first, it finds all `<input>` tags, then looks at the parent, then under the parent node it finds all `.placeholder`s, then does nothing with them.

The second line finds and hides all `.placeholder`s.

What you're probably looking for would look like this:

```
$('#soyadi:focus').parent().find('.placeholder').hide();
```

Or

```
$('#soyadi:focus').closest('.placeholder').hide();
```

The difference is that your `$('.placeholder').hide()` finds ALL of them, while either of these two would find the one closest to it and hide only that one.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. I worked on this for two hours yesterday.